# Texture Paint is either not showing up or looks highlighted?

Tags: texturing, shaders, texture-painting

[image: I created a new image texture mask to paint makeup on. It looks fine in this mode until i go to render mode, and it looks either nonexistent or neon.]

[image: It doesn't look natural. I believe it has something to do with my Nodes below.]

[image: Here are my nodes.]

Not entirely sure what to do, I believe my nodes are incorrect. Any thoughts? I just want the makeup to look more natural. I created a separate Image texture for it, as I thought it be easier to paint on a new mask rather than the existing ones. Any thoughts?